# How to avoid the duplicate values from the combo boxes?

Tags: c#

I am working with 2 combo boxes in windows forms in C#.net .. if i select any country from cmb1 display the states belongs to that country from states table into the combo box2...

If I select any country name from cmb1 with 2 times...the states belong to that country are adding  2 times  in combo box2... how can avoid it ...

code is here

```
private void Form12_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select  cname from country", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        cmbcountry.Items.Add(dr["cname"]);
    }

    con.Close();
}

private void cmbcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select sname from state where cname='"+cmbcountry.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();      
    while (dr.Read())
    {

        cmbstate.Items.Add(dr[0]);
    } 
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'select any country name from cmb1 with 2 times.' 2 times ?

Comment: If you want to add at a time only one countries states then you can clear the combobox at each selection before filling it with states and use the parametrised sql statements.

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the contents of the box before you populate it:

```
cmdState.Items.Clear()
```

Note that your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection (i.e. watch what happens if a country-name has an apostrophe in it, e.g. "Côte d'Ivoire")

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the existing cmbstate.Items and add it again,

```
private void cmbcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbcmbstate.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();           
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select sname from state where cname='"+cmbcountry.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();      
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cmbstate.Items.Add(dr[0]);
        } 
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work - it will clear the list every time it adds a new item - in the end, the list will only contain 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the states in combobox are not getting added automatically, you are explicitly adding it in your code. In fact, it will be added as many times you select the country. The reason is that you are not clearing the states combobox when you select the a country the second or subsequent time. For this, you should clear the states combobox as soon as the selection changes in the countries combobox:

```
cmbstate.Items.Clear();
```

Also, as Dai pointed out the SQL is prone to SQL injection. Try using LINQ to SQL or stored procedures for safer SQL execution.